# Show that any $n \times n$ array based on $\{1,2,..,n\}$ is a Latin Square if and only if it is simultaneously orthogonal to R and C.

Tags: combinatorial-designs, latin-square

I've been reading Design Theory by Zhe-Xian Wan, but I have been stuck on where to begin with this question - Page 95, Exercises 4.7, Question 4.1.

Could someone please give me a hint?

Let

\begin{equation}
R = 
    \begin{pmatrix} 
        1 & 1 & ... & 1\\
        2 & 2 & ... & 2 \\
        \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots \\
        n & n & ... & n 
    \end{pmatrix} 
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
C = 
    \begin{pmatrix} 
        1 & 2 & ... & n\\
        1 & 2 & ... & n \\
        \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots \\
        1 & 2 & ... & n 
    \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

be $n \times n$ arrays.

Show that any $n \times n$ array based $\{1,2,...,n\}$ is a Latin Square if and only if it is simultaneously orthogonal to $R$ and $C$.

Comment: I can give you the following hint: show that an array $M$ is orthogonal to $R$ if and only if every row contains the numbers $1, \ldots, n$. Similarly, $M$ is orthogonal to $C$ if and only if every row contains the numbers $1, \ldots, n$. Beyond that, I'm not sure what other non-answer hint I could give, as the exercise is quite straight forward.

Comment: @Okbko That is not the definition of "orthogonal" that is being used in this context.  Note that "$A$ is orthogonal to $B$" means that $\operatorname{Tr}(A^TB) = 0$.  In other words, the "dot-product" of $A$ and $B$ is zero.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I really doubt that this is the meaning of orthogonality here. I'm sure it's much more likely to be array orthogonality condition: that the map $(i, j) \mapsto (a_{ij}, b_{ij})$ is a bijection onto $\{1, 2, \ldots, n\}^2$.

Comment: @Okbko I think all this discussion about definitions of orthogonality shows that you should probably clarify which definition of orthogonality you mean. Please edit your question, putting the definition you're working with into the body of your question. This should make things more clear for everyone.

Comment: @user759562 I've never heard of heard of that notion of orthogonality, but that version of orthogonality definitely makes this question correct.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I learned about it in my undergrad. There's some study into systems of $n - 1$ [mutually orthogonal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graeco-Latin_square#Mutually_orthogonal_Latin_squares) $n \times n$ latin squares. It's simple enough to construct them when $n$ is a prime power from finite fields, but it is unknown as to whether such a system exists for other values of $n$. This is intimately connected to the problem of categorising finite projective planes.

Comment: @user759562 nifty, thanks for that.

Comment: @user759562 How do you prove the matrix is a Latin square if and only if it orthogonal to these two matrices? I'm still confused. Could you post your solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Orthogonal latin squares are defined [here](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Orthogonal_Latin_squares) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graeco-Latin_square#Mutually_orthogonal_Latin_squares).  The proof should follow from definition.

A latin square $M$ is such that $m_{ij} \neq m_{i'j}$ and $m_{ij} \neq m_{ij'}$ for $i\neq i'$ and $j\neq j'$.  So if $(m_{ij},r_{ij}) = (m_{kl},r_{kl})$, then $m_{ij}=m_{kl}$, in which case $k\neq i$ and $l\neq j$ unless $i,j=k,l$.  And the same business applies with ordered pairs $(m_{ij},c_{ij})$.  So if $M$ is a latin square, it is orthogonal to $R$ and $C$.

Conversely, suppose $M\perp R$ and $M\perp C$.  If $m_{ij}=m_{i'j}$ for $i\neq i'$, then $(m_{ij},c_{ij}) = (m_{i'j},c_{i'j})$.  Similarly, if $m_{ij}=m_{ij'}$ for $j\neq j'$, then $(m_{ij},r_{ij}) = (m_{ij'},r_{ij'})$.  So $M$ is a latin square.